# PHP Multi Form Field Search

Tags: php, mysql

Through doing some reading up & trawling the web Ive managed to build a HTML form & PHP script that will do text search on a MySQL db I have. I can get it to search successfully from text entered into 1 field in a form. I was wondering how to expand this so that I can give users 2 fields & they can enter data in 1 or both of them to refine their results, i.e. search for all entries named 'John', or all entries named 'John' & in the city of 'Dublin'. Ive tried many manipulations of the MySQL query, but havent been successful in getting it to work satisfactorily. How can I write the code below to get this to work?

My HTML form code is:

```
<form method="POST" action="search.php" name="formid">
   Name: <input type="text" name="query" /><br>
   City: <input type="text" name="city" /><br>
   <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Start Search" />
</form>
```

& the PHP code is:

```
<?php

include 'db_details.php';

$connection = mysql_connect($server, $user, $password);

mysql_select_db($db, $connection);

$query=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['query']);

$query = htmlspecialchars($query);

$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM colour WHERE (firstname LIKE '%".$query."%') ", $connection) or die ("Cannot run query");

echo "<h2>Search Results</h2>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    foreach ($row as $attribute)
    echo "{$attribute} ";
    echo "<br>";
}

mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: What do your tables look like (schema) ?  What have you tried so far ?

Comment: add more fields, check if they're filled, build a `WHERE` string to add to the quary based on the fields filled

Answer (score 0):

Just put the value of the city field in a variable `$city`:

```
$city = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);

$city = htmlspecialchars($city);
```

Then query it like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM colour WHERE (firstname LIKE '%".$query."%' OR city LIKE '%".$city."%') ", $connection) or die ("Cannot run query");
```

It will query all results from `colour` where the firstname is like `$query` or the city is like `$city`

Note: there will be no priority in this approach, colours rows that match both conditions will not have a higher priority then rows with only 1 match

For a more advanced search method i'd advise you to look into [Full-text search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html) aswell